# How can I make audio input work with Intel NUC5i3RYK

Tags: sound, intel, soundcard, intel-nuc

That's a bit unusual, but perhaps someone's gonna know... Anyway, I bought an Intel NUC (5i3RYK). Ubuntu 15.04 works just fine and with no issues. Well, almost.

The only problem I'm having is that I can not make my headphones' microphone work with my NUC. The headset has two jacks (input and output). I was able to get sound output from the HDMI (adapter with a separate minijack audio output), but I simply can not make input work.

I plugged the audio jack (the red microphone one) of my headset into the front input/output jack socket, but no sound input device is detected. Also tried with another headset to make sure that it's not the headset issue.

I used alsamixer to make sure that there are no muted devices. The sound card clearly has a "capture" possibility and I can set a volume for it, but sadly it still doesn't work.

When I do `arecord -l`, I get this:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So the device is definitely there.

Any ideas? I'd be grateful.

Comment: what is the output of `arecord` when you're talking into the headset?  (Don't post the whole output, just post like the first few lines)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm not sure how to use arecord. I entered the command but it just displayed a lot of help text.

Comment: When I do 'arecord -l' though, I get this: **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: OK, when you run `arecord -d 2 -f cd -t wav` while talking what do you get?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm getting this while talking:

Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
RIFFDbWAVEfmt D��data bRIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt D��data RIFFDWAVEfmt 

...and so on.

Comment: Well then it looks like it's working.  Run these commands while talking:  `arecord -d 10 -f cd -t wav test.wav; aplay test.wav`

Comment: It recorded a bunch of wav files that were placed in my home folder. I can play them, but it's just silence.
Just to be sure I downloaded a random wav file from the internet and it plays just fine.

Comment: Your sound card may be defunct.  I have one where the physical connection is bad, and that may be your problem.

Comment: Actually I solved it :P. Will post an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using a simple splitter, similar to this one: http://cdn3.volusion.com/yuyf4.pmrj2/v/vspfiles/photos/KM-IPHONE-2TRS-A22-2.jpg
For a reason that is still unknown, my NUC did not want to accept input when I was connecting the microphone cable directly to its jack socket. I simply connected it through that additional splitter cable and voila :). It works :).

Comment: Ah I see what the issue is:  Your computer had a combination input/output.  This splitter gives you traditional jacks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my Intel NUC NUC8I5BEH and Ubuntu 18.04
I added this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

to:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

(After making a backup of the file.)

I then had to reboot my computer. After that I opened gnome alsa-mixer gui and tried turning on and off mute and record, but it still didn't work. These settings were mute unchecked, and rec checked for both headphon and headset when I stopped.

Then I unplugged and replugged my headset and a pop-up with icons appeared. I selected the one that looked like a headset including a microphone.

After that the microphone in the headset worked fine. 
I got the setting from:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a6lkqu/intel_nuc_not_recognizing_mic_input_on_1804/